# Как массив передать в функцию

Tags: javascript, html, css3, html5

Мне нужно чтобы человек вел x и y в инпутах после чего эта информация передовалась в функцию и создавалась таблица 3 на 3 как крестики нолики вот код
но вот нужно с массив в функцию передать как уже голову не ломал сколько вариантов решение не переберал ничего не получаеться

```
var x = document.getElementById("x").value
var tab = document.getElementById("tab");
var y = document.getElementById("y").value
var butt = document.getElementById("butt")
butt.onclick = function() {

for (var f=0; f < x.length; f++) {

var tr = document.createElement("tr")
for (var g=0; g < y.length; g++) {

var td = document.createElement("td");
if (f%2 == g%2) {
    td.className = "border";
}
else{
    td.className = "border";
}
tr.appendChild(td)


}
tab.appendChild(tr)

}
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="game.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Ведите x и y чтобы сделать таблицу</h1>
    x:<input id="x" type="text">
    y:<input id="y" type="text">
    <button id="butt">Ввод</button>
    <table id="tab"></table>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="code.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: А где тут функция? я вижу только переменные

Comment: butt.onclick = function

Comment: под переменными

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так попробуйте

```js
let butt = document.getElementById("butt");
let tab = document.getElementById("tab");

butt.onclick = function() {

 let x = +document.getElementById("x").value;
 
 let y = +document.getElementById("y").value;
  
 for (let f=0; f < x; f++) {
  let tr = document.createElement("tr");
  for (let g=0; g < y; g++) {
    let td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = "0";
    tr.appendChild(td);    
  }
  tab.appendChild(tr);
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="game.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Ведите x и y чтобы сделать таблицу</h1>
    x:<input id="x" type="text">
    y:<input id="y" type="text">
    <button id="butt">Ввод</button>
    <table id="tab"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое